# Import SharePoint calendars into this 3rd party master calendar

Tags: calendar, third-party-software

Currently I'm using [EMS](https://success.emssoftware.com/Older_Releases_(V44%2C_V43)/EMS_Version_44/Installing_and_Setting_Up_EMS/EMS_API) 3rd party master calendar

Now I have to Import SharePoint calendarse events into 3rd party master calendar

Please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of either EMS system support import from Excel or not, but you can export SharePoint Calendar list to excel. Follow the steps:
1. Open the SharePoint Calendar list.
2. Open ribbon and navigate to `Calendar` tab.
3. Under `Connect and Export` section find `Export to Excel`.

This will export your data to excel, which you can use in your third party calendar tool (if 3rd party tool provides an option to).